# Intel WiFi 6 AX200 not working on 22.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, network-manager

I am currently on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and Intel WiFi 6 AX200 is installed on my laptop. Many a times the WiFi Settings Panel says unavailable and also says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". Sometimes the WiFi appears by itself and now its gone. I have installed the latest drivers from https://www.intel.in/content/www/in/.../wireless.html

I searched on some forums on what to do but nothing worked. I ran  `sudo lshw -C network` and got the following output:

```
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 16
       serial: f8:0d:ac:07:f6:6a
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-47-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:52 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fca04000-fca04fff memory:fca00000-fca03fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 1a
       serial: ac:12:03:41:41:28
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-47-generic firmware=66.f1c864e0.0 cc-a0-66.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:78 memory:fc900000-fc903fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: a
       bus info: usb@3:2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 62:1d:4b:b4:65:59
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.15.0-47-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.109.60 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

Currently I am using internet by USB Tethering from my mobile device. I am Dual Boot with Windows 11 the WiFi behaves the same way on that as well.
I have tried disabling Fast Boot on Windows but still the issue persists.

[image: This is the Wifi Settings Screen]

Update:

```
➜  ~ rfkill list
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
➜  ~
```

Comment: do you have a hardware wifi kill switch (or button)?

Comment: I am on a laptop so no there's no wifi kill button.

Comment: Laptops, specifically, are *more* likely to have a hardware wifi switch of some kind. What laptop model? Can you post output of `rfkill list`?

Comment: "I am Dual Boot with Windows 11 the WiFi behaves the same way on that as well." That strongly suggests that the hardware is defective, not properly seated in the PCI slot, etc. That is, a hardware issue and not an operating system issue.

Comment: @chili555 I don' think there is a hardware issue because there are occasions on which the Wi-Fi works perfectly. Today morning I woke up restarted my system to Windows saw the Wi-Fi option on it then rebooted to Ubuntu again and the WiFi option is here now somehow. So I am pretty sure its not a hardware issue.

Comment: @Esther The laptop I have is HP OMEN Laptop 15-en0xxx and somehow the WiFi just got back but I am pretty sure the problem will come back again soon.

Comment: @Esther Now its gone again the same situation has occurred. I have added the output of  `rfkill list` on the post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is relevant, but my mini-PC with an AX200 said something about a stop job waiting for firmware when I rebooted it a couple of days ago (I left it on, but it probably timed out) and the wifi completely flaked out after I brought it back up. Large transfers would always flake out. I installed a wifi dongle to get a reliable connection and did a forced reinstall of linux-firmware. After going back to the AX200 wifi, things have been working (I'll see if that stays true for a few days).

Comment: I have same problem now on Ubuntu 22.04.
rfkill list shows:
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
I now have to use my phone as a hotspot to connect to the internet:
lshw -C shows ethernet as UNCLAIMED:but wi-fi for AX200 looks OK.